# Assign Custom Claims Provider/ Retrieve Configured Claims for Azure AD Application via Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am currently working on integrating a [custom authentication extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/custom-extension-overview) into Microsoft Azure Active Directory.
I saw we can successfully create the custom authentication extension using the Microsoft Graph API in this documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/identitycontainer-post-customauthenticationextensions?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Now, I am facing two specific challenges:

1. **Automating the Assignment of a Custom Claims Provider to My Azure AD Application:**

   While exploring the Microsoft Graph API documentation, I couldn't find a clear method or endpoint for assigning a custom claims provider to an Azure AD application via the microsoft graph api.

I expected this functionality to be [part of the SAML Single Sign-On (SSO) configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/application-saml-sso-configure-api?tabs=http%2Cpowershell-script#step-3-configure-claims-mapping) process, like the manually part,
but I am unsure about the specific steps or API calls involved.

This is the manually configuration in the azure portal-

[image]

2. **Retrieving Configured Attributes & Claims for a Given Application:**

   As part of the SSO configuration for my application, I am interested in retrieving the configured attributes & claims, especially those associated with the custom claims provider.

I couldn't find a clear method for programmatically obtaining these configured claims.

My intention was to see if those configuration could be provided as part of the [application data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)/ while obtaining the [Microsoft Entra SAML metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/application-saml-sso-configure-api?tabs=http%2Cpowershell-script#step-6-get-microsoft-entra-saml-metadata), but I may have been mistaken.

How can I retrieve information about the claims configured for a specific application?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!